# CSOM list item manipulation

Tags: development, client-object-model

Short and sweet : I'm parsing an XML document and adding new job openings into a sharepoint list as  well as  deleting them if the job id's and deleting them if the particular job id is not present in the list item collection.

Here's the question:

> > If i try to query a field value from the item collection that dosent exist, will that cause an error?

```
 foreach (ListItem listItem in items) 
 { 

     console.WriteLine(listItem["Title"]=="XYZ") // say, there is no item with a title "XYZ" 
  }
```

Comment: Are you asking what will happen if the listItem object does not have a value for Title or what will happen if the loop completes without finding a listItem who's Title equals "XYZ"?

Comment: yes , I want to know what will happen if the listItem object does not have a value for Title

Answer (score 2):

If the target list does not have a field (column) named Title you will get a PropertyOrFieldNotInitialized exception. To avoid this exception you can do a check on the FieldValues property which is a Dictionary of all the field names and their associated values.

```
if (item.FieldValues.ContainsKey("Title"))
{
    var value = item["Title"];
}
```